# FloatingEditText class.exception

Tags: android-studio, android-edittext, classcastexception

I'm new to Android Studio. I've changed my app slightly to incorporate the floating TextEdit widget from marvinlabs.

The widget  works fine and does as it is supposed to but when i click the calculate button its tell me the app has stopped working and i get this in my logcat error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.marvinlabs.widget.floatinglabel.edittext.FloatingLabelEditText cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
            at com.motionnetworkz.bonus.BonusCalc.onCalcClick(BonusCalc.java:29)
```

The line of code is:

```
EditText a1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFSalary);
        String strTFSalary = a1.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(strTFSalary)) {
            a1.setError("No Salary Value");
```

Ive changed it to

`com.marvinlabs.widget.floatinglabel.edittext.FloatingLabelEditText a1 = (com.marvinlabs.widget.floatinglabel.edittext.FloatingLabelEditText) findViewById(R.id.TFSalary);
        String strTFSalary = a1.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(strTFSalary)) {
            a1.setError("No Salary Value");`

as this is what it is called within the xml file ( was EditText) but it then throw other errors

`a1.gettext` & `a1.setError` then becomes an error of `cannot resolve method getText()`

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

`FloatingLabelEditText a1 = (FloatingLabelEditText) findViewById(R.id.TFSalary);
        String strTFSalary = a1.getInputWidgetText().toString();`

I didnt need to set the whole `com.marvinlabs...` section just the `FloatingLabelEditText`

then change `getText()` to `getInputWidgetText()`.

Android studio was running very slow and never gave me any options to add to start with. A reboot cleared it up and gave me a list of options. trial and error and all working fine.